# Determine whether destination for file move is on same filesystem in C#

Tags: c#, .net, io, async-await

I have a Windows Forms application which uses `File.Move` to move files in response to user request.  This is not an asynchronous method, but when the destination is on the same drive it happens almost instantly (I assume because it can just rewrite the header and not move anything).  However, it blocks the application if the destination is *not* on the same drive.  Not desirable.

So naturally I thought about switching to async.  It looks like the way to do this is to use file streams and use `Stream.CopyToAsync` before removing the original.  That's fine, except if it *is* on the same drive, this is a lot of wasteful copying.

Is there a reliable way to determine if a proposed destination for a file is on a different drive than that drive is currently stored on before deciding which operation to perform?  I could obviously look at the drive letter, but that seems kind of hacky and I think there are some cases like junction points where it will not work correctly.

Another possible choice is to use something like `Task.Run(() => File.Move(x))`, although I have a vaguely bad feeling about that.

Comment: Drive letter wouldn't necessarily work (I think), what about striped volumes or RAID? - Trying to think of ideas but that's something that came to mind

Comment: @jdphenix Yeah, OK, that's another reason, besides the junction points, not to do it.

Comment: Windows or *nix? Or need something portable?

Comment: @jdphenix Windows.

Comment: @jdphenix: *Windows Forms* and *drive letter* might help you figure that out.

Comment: @KenWhite http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/, I'll give you the point on drive letter though.

Comment: Just do it the right way for *all* moves, regardless of where they are. Don't write a bunch of potentially erroneous code to handle edge cases. If moves on the same disk are fast enough now, they'll be fast enough if you perform them asynchronously.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't see how copying a file on the same disk, then deleting the original, could possibly be just as fast as the move operation, which doesn't have to read the file content at all.

Comment: You don't actually know that's how the move operation is implemented, you're just assuming it is. And that is besides the point. The point is that the difference in speed just doesn't matter. If your second-attempt implementation is sufficiently fast that it works for file moves on different disks, or across a network, then it will *certainly* accommodate file moves on the same disk. Which makes it not only pointless but arguably poor design to have multiple methods of copying files in the code. You'll end up with a bunch of fragile code to try and figure out which one to use.

Comment: @CodyGray Well, it's not really "fast enough."  It's quite slow, which is why I'd like to avoid it when possible.

Comment: @CodyGray The files being moved are video and go up to a couple gigabytes in size; the difference between the almost-instant move operation and the copy operation is quite noticeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best effort for this is going to be comparing volume serial numbers. [`GetFileInformationByHandle()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364952(v=vs.85).aspx) is able to get the volume serial number of a file handle. This is definitely a YMMV for RAID / striped volumes, so if those apply, I would test this solution for the performance. It *does* work for junction points.

The DllImport for it is

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool GetFileInformationByHandle(
    IntPtr hFile,
    out BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION lpFileInformation);
```

We also need a way to get suitable file handles to use. Since we're working with potential destinations, if we assume the destination directory already exists, we can use [`CreateFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) to get a directory handle.

For `CreateFile()`, the DllImport is

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr CreateFile(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string filename,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileAccess access,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileShare share,
    IntPtr securityAttributes,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileMode creationDisposition,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileAttributes flagsAndAttributes,
    IntPtr templateFile);
```

We'll also need `CloseHandle()`,

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
[SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);
```

With all those pieces in place, create a wrapper method that returns true if the volume serial number of the supplied paths match. It obviously makes sense throw more specific exceptions, but for the sake of brevity:

```
static bool SameVolume(string src, string dest)
{
    IntPtr srcHandle = IntPtr.Zero, destHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
    try
    {
        srcHandle = CreateFile(src, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite, IntPtr.Zero,
            FileMode.Open, (FileAttributes) 0x02000000, IntPtr.Zero);
        destHandle = CreateFile(dest, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite, IntPtr.Zero,
            FileMode.Open, (FileAttributes) 0x02000000, IntPtr.Zero);
        var srcInfo = new BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION();
        var destInfo = new BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION();

        if (!GetFileInformationByHandle(srcHandle, out srcInfo))
        {
            throw new Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString());
        }

        if (!GetFileInformationByHandle(destHandle, out destInfo))
        {
            throw new Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString());
        }

        return srcInfo.VolumeSerialNumber == destInfo.VolumeSerialNumber;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (srcHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            CloseHandle(srcHandle);
        }

        if (destHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            CloseHandle(destHandle);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could just use

```
Task.Run(() => File.Move(x))
```

or another asynchronous construct to get this done without locking up the application's interface. I can't see anything wrong with that.

Comment: I'd remembered a lot of stuff saying not to use Task.Run for I/O-bound work, but revisiting it it seems like the rationale for that is not really relevant to me, so you might be right about just pursuing the simple course.  Anyway, this seems to answer everything.